# How to control input type="url" default validation?

Tags: html

I have in a form an input field, its type is url.

I want the field will accepted when I write anything in it.

(I don't want to change the input type).
(Without using Javascript please).

[image]

Do you know how can I make it ? Thank you

Comment: It can't not be possible as you want not to change input type or without using JavaScript. Either you have to change input type or add JavaScript or jQuery to make it accept anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without changing the input type but you can use the pattern to perform custom validation like in the example below

```html
<html>
<form action="/">
<input id="url" name="url" type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{3}" title="Custom Validation/">
<button type="submit" >Submit</buton>
</form>
</html>
```